# What does the dot in the name of the element means?

Tags: javascript

Looking at some javascript code in here I came across this syntax:

```
$(".content").html(data);
```

But what does the dot before the name of the element means?

Comment: It's for a *class* name, not the "name of the element".

Comment: .content means you are accessing an element whose class="content" in HTML

Comment: `$(".content")` is like `document.getElementsByClassName('content')` in terms of what they find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery uses a syntax similar to CSS for selectors:

```
'.content'
```

will select all elements with class content, other typical use is `#` which will select elements by the id. You can learn more about jquery selectors in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)